# Is there any way to compare an array in mongo aggregate?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

This code does not match the **bu.subUser** with **subUser** and due to mismatch nothing is returned. How to achieve the output?

```
{
  $match: {
    subUser: {
      $ne: blockedUsers.map((bu) => {
        return bu.subUser;
      }),
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: Maybe `{$match: {subUser: {$in: blockedUsers.subUser}}}` or `{$match: {subUser: {$in: blockedUsers.map( x => x.subUser) }}}`

Answer (score 1):

```
{ $match: { subUser: { $nin: blockedUsers.map((bu) => bu.subUser) } } }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).